# Azure blob storage download giving 403 error on Android

Tags: android, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am making an Azure Blob storage request in Android using the azure blob storage library. I am getting 403 error as a response. I tried looking into the issue and found the error was with the date and time in the device and the error was:

Request date header too old

I tried getting the device time automatically from the network and thereafter the request worked properly.

But I cant assume all the people using the application would have set their settings to obtain the time automatically. Is there any workaround for this or is there a way by which I can avoid setting the time in the device so that it can be obtained directly at the server end when receiving the request.

Answer (score 0):

The timespan for 403 is about 15~20 minutes. So, it could be enough to give the data. If not, your blob could be overcharged by recursive calls from clients.

Three possible options you can consider.

1. Of course, not all clients have correct clock. For that, you could consider to move selected binaries to CDN.
2. Or, if you can create SAS token, clients could be more accessible as the token is valid for about 4 hours.
3. Changing container to `Public` could be an option, but not recommended as it can make overcharge.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am receiving the error even when the time difference is just 1-2 minutes.